# C# UWP Hide Soft Navigation Bar

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uwp

How can I hide/collapse the navigation bar programmatically at the bottom of the windows 10 (univeral windows platform) application that I am writing for phones?

Handling the StatusBar at the top can be done with:
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hide both, you can use Fullscreen mode instead of hiding the status bar, then the navigation bar will be hidden, too.

Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode()

Comment: That does it! Thanks. This works in the App class in the OnLaunched event! Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();

Comment: Beware of hidden symbols :) ^: `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();`

Comment: there is still a bar in portrait mode